# How to Replace a text by calling Onlyoffice ApI

Tags: onlyoffice

I am using Onlyoffice document Server version 5.0.3 It works fine. find and replace a text in the document editor

Onlyoffice configuration
file: editor.jsp

```
config = {
    "document": {
    "fileType": "docx",
    "key": "Khirz6zTPdfd7",
    "title": "sample.docx",
    "url": "http://192.168.0.1:8080/onlyofficeexample/files/192.168.0.1/sample.docx"
    },
    "documentType": "text",
    "editorConfig": {
        "callbackUrl": "http://192.168.0.1:8080/onlyofficeexample/IndexServlet?type=track&fileName=sample.docx&userAddress=192.168.0.1"
    }
         ........
         .......
  };
var docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder", config);
setTimeout(function(){
      var text_replace = {
        textsearch: "~($#effective_date#$)~",
        textreplace: "23/05/1991",
        matchcase: false,
        matchword: false,
        highlight: true
     };
     docEditor.onReplaceText(text_replace);
}, 30000);
```

I am trying to replace a text with calling API, and have created the further trigger function in Onlyoffice API call.

```
   //trigger function
     onReplaceText: function (data) {
            $me.trigger("onreplacetext", data)
     },
```

here i want find and replace a text based on data passed to this function

```
     onReplaceText:function(data){

     }
    Common.Gateway.on('onreplacetext',_.bind(me.onReplaceText, me));
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

finally, i replaced the text in onlyoffice API by using below code.

```
//trigger function    
 onReplaceText: function (data) {
        $me.trigger("onreplacetext", data)
 },
```

here i want find and replace a text based on data passed to this function

```
 onReplaceText:function(data){
   data=data.data;
   this.api.asc_replaceText(data.textsearch, data.textreplace,true, data.matchcase, data.matchword);
  }
Common.Gateway.on('onreplacetext',_.bind(me.onReplaceText, me));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to use the method of asc_replaceText to modify the content of the document. Your request can be realized by means of document builder (please see this section of API) or by means of plugin. We are also glad to announce that feature list of find-replace method will be added in the following update of the document builder and it will be also available for the plugin.